# how to handle middleware by request action and trigger success action in react+redux?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, flux

I am learning ReactJS by a movie finder app using reactJS+redux. I am putting my github repo here: `https://github.com/ajay28kumar/redux-omdb-movieFind.git`

I am creating one action called **getMovieSearch** that will return the requested data in component as well as make an api call (api call file is in `/api/fetchApi`). After fetching data into api file I am passing that dta to my successAction named **getMovieList** and after that I am returning the same into my reducer **movieGetReducer**. All of these steps are working fine but my store is not getting updated.

I got one alternate solution that **getMovieSearch** will make following call:

```
export var getMovieSearch = (payload) => {
    const request= axios.get("http://www.omdbapi.com/?t="+ payload+ "&page=1");
    console.log("data from api :", request)
    return {
        type: 'GET_MOVIE_LIST',
        payload: request
    };
};
```

It is going to my middleware and working fine but I want to seperate actions for **request / successResponse / errorResponse** for my learning app.

If someone can correct the same then it will great.

Thanks.

Comment: Which middleware are you using for fetching data asynchronously?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [redux-thunk](https://github.com/gaearon/redux-thunk). A common pattern for async actions is that you create 3 actions: request, receive (success) and failed.

Example:

```
export var getMovieSearch = (payload) => (dispatch) => {
  dispatch(requestMovieList(payload));
  axios.get("http://www.omdbapi.com/?t=" + payload + "&page=1")
    .then(res => dispatch(receiveMovieList(res.data)))
    .catch(err => dispatch(getMovieListFailed(err)))
};
```